# Placing images in a list

Tags: android

I am developing an Android application which involves splash screen.

There is a screen containing four `Button`s and four `Tab`s. Now U am facing a problem when I have to show an image in a list.

Can anyone help me in this regard.

Comment: By list do you mean a `ListView`? You have to try to be a bit more precise when formulating your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite simple. In your adapter in the getView Method, you can return an Image or any other view.

See also this tutorial

http://www.androidpeople.com/android-custom-listview-tutorial-example/